# Web api native/web api confusion

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am pretty confused here.
I have a web api working fine, hosted on azure. 
I will be using the web api for both a native wpf application as well as a third party calling the web api for a web app.
I want the wpf app to authenticate against azure AD. To do this I need to set up the application on AD as a native app.
But for the web application do I then need to set up a second web api app for this to be called.
Swagger displays 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page' so reading around I need to set up keys so swagger is available, BUT this requires a web/api app NOT native.
This is my first stab at an answer, so any direction would be gratefully received.
Scott 
PS

Calling the api from wpf I get the following. 
The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the WPF app must be a native app.

And you must use a second app registered as a "Web app / API".

One thing you should do is add the WPF app's client id in the API app's manifest's `knownClientApplications` property. Actually this is only really important in multi-tenant cases, but it doesn't hurt in single-tenant.

Comment: great. many thanks. that clears a few things up for me. Let me run through it and I will tick the answer. cheers for quick reaponse

Comment: Glad to help! :)